# Aapt2 error android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

{

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha12-4662957-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get
  more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

}

Comment: This looks serious, could you please post the whole build log? You can go to the Terminal window in Android Studio and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and post the output here.

Comment: Also maybe check your antivirus? It's probable that it is blocking the new version of AAPT2

Comment: I don't have any sort of antivirus. juz  have that normal default windows one!!

Comment: Okay please run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" or maybe even "gradlew clean assembleDebug --info" and edit this post with the output.

Comment: It actually got resolved when I closed the project and shutdown my pc and then restarted it

Answer (score 0):

Add 
android.enableAapt2=false

in gradle.properties

Comment: But it aaptv1 is gonna end at the end of 2018 so I wanna use aapt2