# Flutter not run

Tags: flutter

I am having problems with initializing the flutter project and running it for the first time and it does not work and shows the following error message. Hope someone helped me. Thanks everyone

Flutter 1.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128806/aapt2-error-android-studio, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535585/gradle-build-failed-after-update-to-3-2-0?rq=1 Doesn't look related to Flutter.

Comment: try running "flutter doctor", if anything is missing?